# Passat B6 FSI Light/Tail light/ Blinker Diagram

Tags: vw, lights, tail-lights, passat, brake-light

I own an 2006 Passat B6 FSI (150 hp) and I want to have a look on wiring diagram. For me is interesting to know voltage when:

1. Tail ligt is ON
2. Brake is pressed
3. Blinker is ON

And what happen when I have brake pressed and turn on bliker: how circuit works.
Thank you!

As I understood, all bulbs works with 12V (11.4v).
But someome know current consumption for tail light, brake and blinkers? (This car use LED for this lights, and I think is Osram Lsy676- OEM )

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Well, in general, the answer to your question of "... interesting to know voltage when:" is ... 12vdc. That is system voltage. That's what gets applied to the bulbs.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.